# FCM and Typescript Async Await: Network Timing Out

Tags: typescript, async-await, firebase-cloud-messaging, google-cloud-functions

I'm new to Typescript and I'm trying to use the async and await functionality. I'm getting some fcm network timeouts every once in a while and I believe it has to do with not returning my promises correctly.

Here is my cloud function for sending a push notification. The two functions that are using the await keyword are `incrementBadgeCount`, and `sendPushNotification`:

```
export const pushNotification = functions.firestore
  .document('company/{companyId}/message/{messageId}/chat/{chatId}')
  .onCreate(async event => {

const message = event.data.data();
const recipients = event.data.data().read;
const messageId = event.params.messageId;

const ids = [];
for (const key of Object.keys(recipients)) {
    const val = recipients[key];
    if (val === false) {
        ids.push(key);
    }
}

return await Promise.all(ids.map(async (id) => {
    const memberPayload = await incrementBadgeCount(id);
    const memberBadgeNumberString = 
      memberPayload.getBadgeCount().toString();

    const senderName = message.sender.name;
    const senderId = message.sender.id;
    const senderMemberName = message.senderMember.name;
    const toId = message.receiver.id;
    const text = message.text;
    const photoURL = message.photoURL;
    const videoURL = message.videoURL;
    const dealId = message.dealId;
    const dealName = message.dealName;

    const payload = {
        notification: {
          title: `${senderName}`,
          click_action: 'exchange.booth.message',
          sound: 'default',
          badge: memberBadgeNumberString
        },
        data: { senderId, toId, messageId }
    };

    const options = {
        contentAvailable: true
    }

    ........

    const deviceIDs = memberPayload.getDeviceID()
    return await sendPushNotification(id, deviceIDs, payload, options);
  }));
});
```

Here is the `incrementBadgeCount` function that increases the badge count for the payload and returns some info for the payload:

```
async function incrementBadgeCount(memberID: string): 
  Promise<MemberPushNotificaitonInfo> {
const fs = admin.firestore();
const trans = await fs.runTransaction(async transaction => {
    const docRef = fs.doc(`member/${memberID}`);
    return transaction.get(docRef).then(doc => {
            let count: number = doc.get('badgeCount') || 0;
            const ids: Object = doc.get('deviceToken');
            transaction.update(docRef, {badgeCount: ++count});
            const memberPayload = new MemberPushNotificaitonInfo(count, ids);
            return Promise.resolve(memberPayload);
    });
});
return trans
}
```

And finally the `sendPushNotification` function that interfaces with FCM and sends the payload off and cleans up bad device tokens:

```
async function sendPushNotification(memberID: string, deviceIDs: string[], payload: any, options: any) {
if (typeof deviceIDs === 'undefined') {
    console.log("member does not have deviceToken");
    return Promise.resolve();
}

const response = await admin.messaging().sendToDevice(deviceIDs, payload, options);
const tokensToRemove = [];
response.results.forEach((result, index) => {
    const error = result.error;
    const success = result.messageId;
    if (success) {
        console.log("success messageID:", success);
        return 
    }
    if (error) { 
        const failureDeviceID = deviceIDs[index];
        console.error(`error with ID: ${failureDeviceID}`, error);

        if (error.code === 'messaging/invalid-registration-token' ||
            error.code === 'messaging/registration-token-not-registered') {
            const doc = admin.firestore().doc(`member/${memberID}`);
             tokensToRemove.push(doc.update({
                deviceToken: {
                    failureDeviceID: FieldValue.delete()
                }
            }));
        }
    }
});

return Promise.all(tokensToRemove);
}
```

I would appreciate some help on tightening this typescript up :)

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, there is some function that you are calling on the firebase api that should be `await`ed, but isn't. I'm not familiar with firebase to tell you exactly which one it is, but it seems like any call to firebase API is potentially `await`able.

This is where ensuring you have type definitions installed for firebase and using a good editor comes in. Take a look at all of your firebase calls and make sure none of them are secretly returning a promise.

Also, you should make sure that all of your functions and variables are as strongly typed as possible, since this will help you avoid any problems.

So, the following lines look suspicious to me:

```
fs.doc(`member/${memberID}`);

transaction.update(docRef, {badgeCount: ++count});

const doc = admin.firestore().doc(`member/${memberID}`);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are opening too many http connections to send push notifications, ideally you should create batch of 5,10 .. to send push.

Try changing,

```
return await Promise.all(ids.map(async (id) => { ... });
```

to,

```
while(ids.length) {
    var batch = ids.splice(0, ids.length >= 5 ? 5 : ids.length);
    await Promise.all(batch.map( async (id) => { ... });
}
```